# What is the equivalent C# of a parameterized type like Class<? extends Throwable> in Java?

Tags: java, c#, exception, generics, parameterized

I wrote this blog: http://tri-katch.blogspot.com and implemented the pahakia-fault library: https://github.com/pahakia/lib.

I'd like to convert the pahakia-fault library to C#.  But how to translate the following into C#?

```
public CodeBlockWorker<T> ignore(Class<? extends Throwable> clazz,
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Class<? extends Throwable>... classes) {
    String[] codes = new String[classes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        Class<? extends Throwable> clz = classes[i];
        codes[i] = clz.getName();
    }
    handlers.add(new KatchHandler<T>(clazz.getName(), codes));
    return this;
}
```

I know C# has Type as the equivalent of Class in Java but Type is not parameterized.

So how to represent a parameterized type in C# if I want to use the type itself instead of an instance of it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't, but it's entirely possible that it would be better to use generics for this. Bear in mind that exceptions in .NET are already different to those in Java, so it's not at all clear that you'd want to take the same approach anyway...

Comment: I think the current Exception model in Java/C# (even C++) is wrong.  We should catch instance of exception code instead of exception class.  Before that happens, the library is just a workaround.

Comment: Well your code specifically talks about classes rather than instances. Anyway, as I say, there's no direct equivalent of this in C#. You could have `Ignore<T>(...) where T : Exception` but that doesn't help for the varargs parameter.

Comment: even without the varargs, I could not find the equivalent of `Class<? extends Throwable>` as the method is using the type itself not an instance of it.  If you think I am wrong (I could be because I am totally new to C#), please give an example without the varargs.  Thanks.

Comment: I've already said twice that there *isn't* an equivalent. But I've suggested you might use a generic method instead, and use the type parameter instead of a normal parameter.

Comment: you're right.  There is no equivalent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My java is a bit rusty, but I think what you are trying to accomplish can be done by using the [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the type of the passed parameters:

```
public CodeBlockWorker<T> Ignore(
      Exception clazz, params Exception[] classes)
{

    handlers.add(
       new KatchHandler<T>(
           //You can use FullName if you want to include the namespace
           clazz.GetType().Name, 
           classes.Select(t => t.GetType().Name)
           /* might need to call .ToArray() if your Constructor expects an array */);

    return this;
}
```

Right so a bit about what's going on.  As any "throwable" exception (ie one that can be used in a try/catch) in .Net must inherit from `Exception` you can set your method parameters to use `Exception`.  The `params` keyword is just a hint to the compiler that allows multiple method parameters to be automatically passed as an array.

`Object` in .net has the method `GetType` which will return the Type for that instance.  You can that get either just the class name via `Name` or the class name and namespace via `FullName`. You can also use the keyword `typeof` to get the Type of a generic parameter.

Finally a bit of linq goodness with the `.Select` method, which performs a transformation / projection over an enumerable (ie array), in this case returning an enumerable of every name in `classes`.

**Update**

If you are trying to work on Types instead of instances of exceptions you could also try and write your method using generic type parameters and the `typeof` keyword to get the type of the type parameters:

```
 public CodeBlockWorker<T> Ignore<TClazz, TClasses>()
    where TCLazz : Exception
    where TClasses : Exception
 {
     var typename = typeof(TClazz).Name;
 }
```

The `where` clauses force the caller to pass in an exception class:

```
 Ignore<NullReferenceException, ArgumentException>();
```

If you wanted to allow the caller to put multiple `TClasses` you'd have to create additional method overloads for each additional type (which is how this is done for [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 Ignore<TClazz, T1, T2>(){}
 Ignore<TClazz, T1, T2, T3>(){}
```

However, you could have each of these overrides feed into the same method:

```
 private CodeBlockWorker<T> DoWork(Type TClazz, params Type[] TClasses){}
 public CodeBlockWorker<T> Ignore<TClazz, T1, T2, T3>()
 {
     return DoWork(typeof(TClazz), typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3));
 }
```

Or you could write it such that the caller has to pass in types, but there isn't a way to restrict the values passed in at compile time; just as you can't create a method that has an integer parameter that restricts the value to '5' and '42'; you can only do this at run time.

```
Ignore(Type clazz, params Type[] classes){

    var typename = clazz.Name;
}
```

This would be called as:

```
Ignore(
    typeof(NullReferenceException), 
    typeof(ArgumentException), 
    typeof(DivideByZeroException));
```

Comment: for `Ignore<NullReferenceException, ArgumentException>();`, is it possible to replace `ArguementException` with `params` too?

Comment: I used what you suggested: `private CodeBlockWorker<T> DoWork(Type TClazz, params Type[] TClasses){}`:

Comment: `CodeBlockWorker<T> katch (KatchBlock<T> katchBlock, Type clazz, params Type[] classes)`

Comment: Thanks.  The code is here:   https://github.com/pahakia/csharplib.  To be exact: https://github.com/pahakia/csharplib/blob/master/pahakia/console/PahakiaFault.cs